# Why does the second program work but not the first?

Tags: python, if-statement, modulus

First :

```
a = int(input())
if a%4 == 0:
    a += 1
if a%4 != 0:
    a -= 1
print(a)
```

Second :

```
a = int(input())
b = a%4
if b == 0:
    a += 1
if b != 0:
    a -= 1
print(a)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: You may also be interested in the keyword `else`

Comment: In the first program you are working on same a so it will enter to both your condition, while second you have assigned it to a variable b which makes the if check only on condition. Add else as mentioned by @harold or write cases

Answer (score 8):

The first will have possibly modified `a` before the second `if` condition is evaluated, and so behaves differently:

```
if a%4 == 0:
    a += 1 # this influences the result of the next IF
if a%4 != 0:
    a -= 1
```

In fact, in this particular case, if the first condition is true, then after 1 is added to `a`, the second condition will also be true, and so `a` gets 1 deducted from it again.

The **second version** first stores in `b` the result needed for the conditions to work on the *original* input value, and only then performs the modification of `a`, which is no longer playing a role in the `if` conditions. There, it is guaranteed that only one of the two `if` conditions is true.

However, most would just use `else`, which removes this problem:

```
if a%4 == 0:
    a += 1
else:
    a -= 1
```

Comment: I'd add some explanation *why* it happens: Each `if` starts a separate comparison block and is entered (and checked) independently. To avoid multiple checks when prior check was true, you can use any number or `elif` (else if) or a generic `else` block. :)

Comment: I think I already did that, but your comment can be of information to future readers.

Comment: Well, you only explained that second if *is* evaluated, not *why* it is evaluated. ;) It's a common beginner problem in many languages that they use ifs instead of elifs/else ifs and only telling them to use else might not help them much in the future (sometimes two separate if blocks are needed - a few days ago there was exactly this case here on SO).

Comment: Just for fun a solution without an `if`: `a += (1, -1)[bool(a%4)]`

Comment: @h4z3, Maybe you see a problem of misunderstanding that I fail to see, but no problem ;-)

Comment: @Matthias, indeed, or `a += 2*(not a%4)-1`

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Now I got it.